# create ObjectListView dynamic

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I would fill a ObjectListView with columns and rows, but my simple programm crashes without error. What is wrong? My designated target is to create a ListView from a database with an unknown schema. Why I don't know about the column names, i need to create the aspect getters dynamicaly. I have experimented with ObjectListView but I failed to add a Row to the ListView.

edit: (stupid code deleted)
I've solved my problem, thanks for the hint with AllColumns and RebuildColumns()

```
            foreach (TTablecolumn c in table.Columns) {
                // Spalte zum Zeigen der aktuellen Werte einfügen ...
                col = new OLVColumn(c.Columnname + " (ALT)", "value");
                col.AspectGetter = delegate(object x) { return ((XmlStuff.Row)x).getColumnByName(c.Columnname).Value; };
                col.IsEditable = false;
                lv.AllColumns.Add(col);

                // Spalte zum Zeigen des neuen Wertes
                col = new OLVColumn(c.Columnname, "newvalue");
                col.AspectGetter = delegate(object x) { return ((XmlStuff.Row)x).getColumnByName(c.Columnname).NewValue; };
                col.IsEditable = true;
                lv.AllColumns.Add(col);

                createViewField(c);
            }
            lv.RebuildColumns();
```

Comment: if it crashes without error I would recommend using the `Debugger` and stepping line by line thru the code..

Answer (score 1):

In terms of how to program an ObjectListView, the existing documentation gives some answers:

- Add columns according info given in [the FAQ](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/faq.html#how-do-i-add-or-remove-a-column-programmatically)
- Don't add `OLVListItems`, as explained in the [Getting Started](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/gettingStarted.html#unlearn-you-must) guide.

So, you will need something like this:

```
lv.AllColumns.Add(col1);
lv.AllColumns.Add(col2);
lv.RebuildColumns();

var list = new List<Model>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
    list.Add(new Model());
lv.SetObjects(list);
```

However, nothing in your code would cause the program to hard crash. You will have to look elsewhere for the source of the crash.